# Unable to run my debug app because this glide error

Tags: java, android, android-glide

How to overcome this new error
Glide version 4.9.0,

ERROR1 :

> cannot found symbol class GlideDrawable

Error 2 :

> wrong number of type argument required 1

Im not a programmer, Im just starting my first project using some readymade script..So I wish I can catch up with all your kind replies.

I already try changing 'GlideDrawable' to 'Drawable'  like how everyones told in this type of problems.. but the same error occur again like, 'cannot found symbol class Drawable'

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target; 

Glide.with(context)
                .load(product.getImages().get(0).getSrc())
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model,         Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.cover_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.cover_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0):

GlideDrawable is depreciated in 4.x version so if you are moving from 3.x to 4.x simple use Drawable.

For example if you are using listener somewhere in code then move to simple this method..

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .load(product.getImages().get(0).getSrc())
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                     holder.cover_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.cover_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
```